# how to get signer for the CPI?

Tags: cpi, signature

Here's my solana program,

```
use my-rust-crate::do_cpi;


pub fn do_something(ctx:Context<DoSomething>) => Result<()>{
    do_cpi(ctx);
}
```

so this my rust crate is where the CPI happens, its not a solana program, its a rust program. In order to do the CPI i need a signer.

so how should i proceed with this.

this is the solana program function i'm try to CPI

```
pub fn register_client(ctx: Context<RegisterClient>, client_name: String) -> Result<()> {
        let name = client_name.as_bytes();

        if validate_name(name) == false {
            return err!(AgentError::InvalidName);
        }
        let client = &mut ctx.accounts.client.load_init()?;
        client.owner = ctx.accounts.owner.to_account_info().key();
        Ok(())
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's say we have `puppet-master` which is our main program that wants to CPI into `puppet` program.

CPIs extend the privileges of the caller to the callee. If an account is passed as a mutable account to the puppet-master then it was still mutable in the puppet program as well, The same applies to signatures (Signers).

Source:
https://book.anchor-lang.com/anchor_in_depth/CPIs.html#privilege-extension

Example with `authority` as the signer.

```
 let cpi_program = self.puppet_program.to_account_info();
        let cpi_accounts = SetData {
            puppet: self.puppet.to_account_info(),
            authority: self.authority.to_account_info()
        };
        CpiContext::new(cpi_program, cpi_accounts)
```

Comment: but my program flow is like this `puppet-master`(solana program) -> `A rust program`(not solana program) -> `Puppet` (CPI target program)

Comment: You can only CPI into deployed Solana programs. You can't CPI into rust programs

Comment: any work around that? like passing signature in some way?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. If you are trying to invoke a rust program from a Solana program, you can't. It should be either deployed in a Solana program or the code exists inside the Solana program. Solana programs have no ability to interact with off-chain programs whatsoever.